# apigee SOAP validation

Tags: validation, soap, apigee

I'd like to validate a soap request wrapped in MTOM via Apigee SOAP Message Validation against a WSDL file.

When I submit the request with header

Content-type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml";start="http://tempuri.org/0";boundary="uuid:4fa9f99a-7f53-4ac6-84ff-05655e9af89c+id=22";start-info="text/xml"

The validation policy seems to just pass-through / not trigger.  I put bogus info into the envelope, but it does not fail.  I've seen a post where someone mentioned that in order for the SOAP Validation policy to trigger, the header must specify Content-type: "application/xml".  If I do so, then the MTOM wrapping causes problems since the request body is not pure XML:

Ex. MTOM wrapper:
--uuid:4fa9f99a-7f53-4ac6-84ff-05655e9af89c+id=22
Content-ID: http://tempuri.org/0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"

So, the long-winded (sorry) way to ask this quesiton:  HOW DO I USE SOAP MESSAGE VALIDATION POLICY IN APIGEE IF IT EXPECTS PURE XML AND I HAVE MTOM WRAPPER?

Side note, I tried extracting the SOAP message/envelope itself into a variable (bodyvar) and having the policy source defined as that variable, but then APIGEE complains that the variable does not resolve to a message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<MessageValidation async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="WSDL_VALIDATION">
    <DisplayName>WSDL_VALIDATION</DisplayName>
    <FaultRules/>
    <Properties/>
    <SOAPMessage />
  <Element namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">Body</Element>
    <Source>bodyvar</Source>
    <ResourceURL>wsdl://FormRequest.wsdl</ResourceURL>
</MessageValidation>
```

Running this give me this fault:
{"fault":{"faultstring":"Variable env does not resolve to a Message","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.messagevalidation.NonMessageVariable"}}}

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the soap message validation only works if the content-type is application/xml. I am guessing you need to set the content-type to the above mentioned value so that your backend understands it. So what I would suggest is this:
- while sending the message from the client, send it as application/xml
- once the soap message is validated, you can use assign message or javascript policy to set the content-type header to your desired, before sending it to the target.

Hopefully, this approach works for you.